# Single-tenant to multi-tenant: restore old database to schema in new database

Tags: postgresql, restore, postgresql-9.3, psql, multi-tenant

I have a Django app which uses Postgres as a database w/ the django-tenants package providing multitenant functionality. This is a migration from what was originally a single tenant database with just one public schema; each tenant will now have its own schema with tables created for each tenant and there is a shared public schema which has a few shared tables (e.g. the table which lists the tenants).

I want to transfer all of the data from the old database into a tenant schema in the new database. I have a database dump file from pg_dump, but I can't see any way to get data back into the tables with pg_restore or psql. Is there a way of getting the data back into the database without having to write scripts?

Hope my question isn't too confusing and I'm using the terminology correctly.

Thanks

Comment: You say: "_I can't see a way ... with pg_restore_" Have you had a look at the example on the [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html)? Can you describe what about it didn't work?

Comment: @PeterVandivier I tried `pg_restore -d newdb --schema=newschema olddb.dump` to no avail. I just found this answer which I somehow missed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260042/how-to-restore-public-schema-into-different-schema, I think that might be the issue